# place vials in your centrifuge

Tags: code-golf, math

This question originates in [this reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/mathriddles/comments/28kgo7/a_centrifuge/) by reddit user taho_teg but it is expanded to a more general 'puzzle'.

You have a centrifuge with 24 holes for the vials uniformly distributed in a circle around the central axis. If you now have a number of vials and you want to start the centrifuge, you need to make sure that they are placed in a balanced manner. The only numbers of vials you cannot balance are 1 and 23. You can for example balance 4 obviously, but you can also balance 5 by making a 'triangle' with 3 vials and placing the other two on two opposite sites.

## Goal

You have to write a program that accepts the number of holes (that are uniformly distributed in a circle around the rotating axis) of your centrifuge as input, and that outputs a list of numbers of vials that cannot be balanced in the centrifuge.

You have to do the calculation and cannot just hardcode the precomputed solutions.

Input and output have to be implemented in a way so that the program code does not have to be changed for calling the program for different inputs. It is also acceptable to write a function (or a similar construct in your language) that can be called via a console.

Be also aware that if you have 6 holes in your centrifuge, you can centrifuge 2 and 3 vials, but you cannot balance 5 since the 'triangle' and the opposite two will overlap at one point. Another example would be for n=15 you cannot balance 11 vials, you can balance 6 and 5 vials, but the combination of those solutions will overlap (this is of course not yet the criterion that it is impossible to do so).

#### Update

It seems some people did not understand the given example, so I made a graphic here. **PLEASE** write a short description of how your algorithm works as well as some example outputs for verification. Please include following examples:

```
n = 1, 6, 10, 24, 63, 100 = 10^2, 163 (prime), 40320 = 8!, 65536=2^2^2^2^2, 105953 (prime)
```

Note that 40320 and 65536 will produce huge lists, it will perhaps be a good idea to only indicate the length of those lists.

If you know some interesting numbers to add to that list please let me know!
The algorithm should work at least up to n = 1'000'000.
[image: 5 vials placed balanced on a 24 hole centrifuge]

#### Example outputs:

These are some example outputs-but perhaps faulty because I just calculated them manually.

```
1: 1
2: 1
3: 1,2
4: 1,3
5: 1,2,3,4
6: 1,5
7: 1,2,3,4,5,6
8: 1,3,5,7
9: 1,2,4,5,7,8
10:1,3,7,9
11:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
12:1,11
13:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
14:1,3,5,9,11,13
15:1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14
```

#### Hint

If you have a centrifuge with *n* holes, and you cannot balance e.g. *6* vials, you will also not be able to blance *n-6* vials - it is basically the same task to balance *m* vials on an empty centrifuge or to balance a filled centrifuge by taking away *m* vials. So you if you have the number *m* in your list you will also have to include *n-m*.

Comment: Shouldn't we need to have the vials evenly spaced to be balanced? I fail to see how the 5 vials in 24 holes example satisfies this. One "half" of the centrifuge will have more vials than the other half. That sounds like the definition of unbalanced to me.

Comment: @Thorn Ignore the 2 vials and concentrate on the 3 vials in an (equilateral) triangle. You have 1 vial at 0 degrees, one at 120 degrees, and one at 240 degrees. So yes, you have one vial at the top (at vertical distance R from the axle) and two at the bottom, but the bottom ones are at vertical distance R/2 from the axle (and horizontal distance `R*sqrt(3)/2`) So being an equilateral triangle it all balances. *(Then you can add your other 2 vials at 90 degrees and 270 degrees.)*

Comment: That still sounds unbalanced. Lets represent it like this:

Comment: @steveverrill That still sounds unbalanced. Lets represent it like this:     10000000 10000000 10000000 (spaces just added for readability). 1 = occupied space with vial, 0=empty. Clearly 3 vials in 24 slots is balanced. If we add two vials to this configuration, we are not balanced. Adding a vial at 90 degrees and 270 gives us this: 10001000 10000000 10001000. We can draw a line of symmetry and see that it divides the centrifuge into two parts of unequal weight. The first half of the bits contain 3 vases while the second half contain 2.

Comment: I think that by "balanced" what is meant is that the centre of mass of the vials is vertically above or below the centre of mass of the centrifuge.

Comment: @Thorn you need to think in two dimensions, not one. The coordinates of the first 3 vials are (0,1), (-sqrt(3)/2,-1/2) and (+sqrt(3)/2,-1/2.) The 5 vial arrangement is not symmetric (apart from possibly a mirror plane) but it is balanced. It's quite common for car wheels to have different numbers of spokes and wheelnuts (again, not symmetrical, but fully balanced because the spokes form a balanced set and the nuts form a balanced set.) Google `7 spoke wheel` and have a look.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "You have to do the calculation and cannot just hardcode the precomputed solutions." Does the code actually have to try every possibility to output a number it claims is impossible?

Comment: Is there an expected range for the number of holes?  You gave the example of 24, but should our programs also work with 1023 holes?  Some methods would be unpractical for higher numbers of holes.

Comment: @xnor No you do not have to try every possible output, you can use basic number theory for eliminating many possibilities.

Comment: @JeffSB I updated it, I think at up to at least one million is reasonable.

Comment: @Thorn I included the example I provided as a graphic.

Comment: The center of gravity definition of "balanced" makes it perfectly clear. But the graphic is a nice touch.

Comment: “The algorithm should work at least up to n = 1'000'000.” Just to be sure: Did you really mean *the algorithm* or did you mean *the program?* My algorithm works as well for n = 1.000.000 as it does for n = 10. The program however, has some issues.

Comment: 63 is not a prime number

Comment: @steveverrill I still don't get the 'balanced' think. Googling 7 spike wheel all I find is perfectly simmetric and balanced. Nothin to do with out 24 holes examples.

Comment: Nexus and Wrzlprmft, thank you for reporting those errorss. @edc65 did you look at the image? (I am not refering to the 7 spike wheel, I know nothing about it) The key is that if you have two solutions where the center of mass is right on the rotating axis, you can combine them (as long as you do nto get 'overlaps' - two vials in the same hole) and even though this comibination is not symmetric, it can still be balanced.

Comment: @edc65. balanced != symmetrical... so long as you break your vials into sub-groups, where each sub-group is in a symmetrical state, then the sum outward force of all sub-groups will be in a balanced state.

Comment: Can you add a more formal definition of "balanced" to the question? Based on the discussion here, it sounds like it means "center of mass is in the center". If that's correct, this definition would actually be a whole lot easier and clearer than what you have with all the examples and figures.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yes that's correct. (Assuming all vials have the same mass.) I originally thought that was the intuitively the first thing you might think of, but some people did not agree as far as I remember!

Answer (score 5):

## Sage – <s>102</s> 104/115

Why use number theory, when there is brute force?

```python
v=lambda n:[j for j in range(n+1)if all(sum(e^(i*2*I*pi/n)for i in c)for c in Combinations(range(n),j))]
```

For a given number of vials, this goes over all ways to position the vials and calculates their center of mass by using complex arithmetics. If the center of mass is zero for none of these ways, the number is returned.

Unfortunately, this does not work in certain cases (10,14), because Sage fails to simplify some expressions to zero (which may be related to [this bug](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/16724)). One could regard this as a flaw of the interpreter and not the program and still say that the algorithm and program are fine.

The following 113-character alternative relies on floats instead of symbols and does not suffer from these problems:

```python
v=lambda n:[j for j in range(n+1)if all(abs(sum(exp(i*2j*pi/n)for i in c))>1e-9for c in Combinations(range(n),j))]
```

---

Test output of the 113-character version (`for n in range(14): print n,v(n)`):

```
0 []
1 [1]
2 [1]
3 [1, 2]
4 [1, 3]
5 [1, 2, 3, 4]
6 [1, 5]
7 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
8 [1, 3, 5, 7]
9 [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
10 [1, 3, 7, 9]
11 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
12 [1, 11]
13 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
14 [1, 3, 5, 9, 11, 13]
```

I did not want to wait the runtime for higher `n`.

---

This originates from the following Python solution. Exact arithmetics and not having to import some modules is quite something.

## Python – <s>173 154</s> 156

```python
from itertools import*
from cmath import*
v=lambda n:[j for j in range(n+1)if all(abs(sum(exp(i*2j*pi/n)for i in c))>1e-9for c in combinations(range(n),j))]
```

Test output of this variant (`for n in range(24): print n,v(n)`):

```
0 []
1 [1]
2 [1]
3 [1, 2]
4 [1, 3]
5 [1, 2, 3, 4]
6 [1, 5]
7 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
8 [1, 3, 5, 7]
9 [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
10 [1, 3, 7, 9]
11 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
12 [1, 11]
13 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
14 [1, 3, 5, 9, 11, 13]
15 [1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14]
16 [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
17 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
18 [1, 17]
19 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
20 [1, 3, 17, 19]
21 [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 20]
22 [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21]
23 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
24 [1, 23]
```

I did not want to wait the runtime for higher `n`.

Comment: I like the idea of using the complex unit roots! Could you please show some example outputs just for verification? I posted some suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

## Lua - 197

A non brute force method, it creates a list of factors and rules them out. It also rules out numbers that can be gotten with the addition of those factors as long as the greatest factor used is less than the amount of unfilled holes. One is always printed and isn't used in the algorithm.

```lua
i=io.read("*n")f={}print(1)for z=2,i do
x=z
if i%x<1 then
table.insert(f,1,x)end
for q=1,#f do
y=f[q]x=x*math.min(1,z%y)while x>=y and x-1~=y and y<=i-z do x=x-y end
end
if x>0 then print(z)end
end
```

Example output: (some put as ranges so I don't exceed the character limit)

```
1: 1

6: 1,5

10:1,3,7,9

24:1,23

63:1,2,4,5,8,11,13,17,20,22,23,25,26,29,32,34,38,41,44,47,50,53,58,59,61,62

100:1,3,13,23,33,43,53,63,73,83,93,97,99

163:1-162

40320:1,11,13,17,19,29,31,37,41,43,61,71,73,97,113,121,127,139,157,169,179,181,191,193,209,211,221,223,241,251,253,263,269,271,277,281,289,299,307,313,331,337,347,349,353,361,373,377,379,397,401,403,409,421,431,433,437,439,449,461,467,473,479,481,491,493,499,517,521,523,529,533,541,547,571,577,587,589,593,601,607,613,617,619,631,641,653,659,671,673,683,689,691,697,701,703,709,713,731,733,737,739,751,757,761,769,781,793,811,817,841,851,853,857,859,869,871,877,881,883,907,913,929,937,953,961,971,977,979,989,991,997,1003,1009,1019,1021,1027,1033,1037,1039,1049,1051,1069,1073,1079,1081,1093,1121,1133,1139,1151,1153,1163,1171,1177,1181,1189,1193,1201,1213,1217,1223,1237,1243,1249,1261,1271,1273,1277,1279,1289,1291,1297,1301,1303,1321,1331,1333,1357,1361,1363,1369,1373,1381,1387,1409,1417,1429,1441,1451,1453,1457,1459,1469,1471,1481,1483,1489,1501,1511,1513,1531,1537,1553,1567,1579,1597,1601,1609,1619,1621,1633,1643,1649,1651,1661,1663,1681,1691,1693,1697,1699,1709,1711,1717,1721,1723,1741,1751,1753,1777,1793,1801,1807,1819,1837,1849,1859,1861,1871,1873,1889,1891,1901,1903,1921,1931,1933,1937,1949,1951,1957,1961,1963,1969,1991,1993,2011,2017,2027,2029,2033,2041,2047,2053,2057,2059,2077,2081,2087,2089,2101,2113,2129,2137,2143,2161,2171,2173,2197,2207,2209,2221,2227,2237,2239,2251,2257,2269,2273,2281,2297,2311,2321,2353,2369,2381,2419,2431,2449,2461,2477,2491,2503,2509,2521,2531,2533,2537,2539,2549,2551,2557,2561,2563,2581,2591,2593,2617,2633,2641,2647,2659,2677,2689,2699,2701,2707,2713,2717,2719,2729,2731,2749,2753,2759,2761,2773,2801,2809,2827,2833,2843,2857,2867,2869,2879,2881,2893,2897,2899,2909,2911,2917,2921,2923,2929,2941,2951,2953,2971,2977,2993,3001,3007,3019,3037,3041,3049,3061,3071,3083,3089,3091,3103,3121,3131,3133,3149,3151,3161,3169,3179,3181,3187,3193,3211,3217,3229,3233,3251,3253,3257,3259,3277,3281,3289,3293,3301,3313,3317,3319,3329,3341,3347,3359,3361,3371,3373,3377,3379,3389,3391,3397,3401,3403,3421,3431,3433,3457,3473,3481,3487,3499,3517,3529,3539,3541,3551,3553,3569,3571,3581,3583,3601,3611,3613,3623,3629,3631,3637,3641,3649,3659,3667,3673,3691,3697,3707,3709,3713,3721,3733,3737,3739,3757,3761,3763,3769,3781,3791,3793,3797,3799,3809,3821,3827,3833,3839,3841,3851,3853,3859,3877,3881,3883,3889,3893,3901,3907,3931,3937,3947,3949,3953,3961,3967,3973,3977,3979,3991,4001,4013,4019,4031,4033,4043,4049,4051,4057,4061,4063,4069,4073,4093,4097,4103,4117,4129,4153,4159,4171,4177,4187,4189,4201,4211,4213,4223,4237,4241,4243,4253,4267,4273,4283,4297,4301,4303,4309,4313,4321,4331,4337,4339,4363,4369,4379,4381,4387,4393,4409,4411,4427,4429,4433,4441,4447,4453,4463,4469,4471,4477,4481,4493,4499,4511,4513,4517,4523,4537,4541,4553,4561,4577,4601,4607,4609,4619,4621,4637,4649,4661,4673,4691,4703,4717,4721,4733,4751,4757,4769,4787,4793,4801,4811,4813,4817,4829,4841,4853,4859,4877,4883,4889,4897,4901,4913,4919,4939,4957,4961,4973,4979,4997,5003,5009,5017,5021,5027,5041,5051,5053,5057,5059,5069,5071,5077,5081,5083,5101,5111,5113,5137,5153,5161,5167,5179,5197,5209,5219,5221,5231,5233,5249,5251,5261,5263,5281,5291,5293,5303,5309,5311,5317,5321,5329,5339,5347,5353,5371,5377,5387,5389,5393,5401,5413,5417,5419,5437,5441,5443,5449,5461,5471,5473,5477,5479,5489,5501,5507,5513,5519,5521,5531,5533,5539,5557,5561,5563,5569,5573,5581,5587,5611,5617,5627,5629,5633,5641,5647,5653,5657,5659,5671,5681,5693,5699,5711,5713,5723,5729,5731,5737,5741,5743,5749,5753,5771,5773,5777,5779,5791,5797,5801,5809,5821,5833,5851,5857,5881,5899,5917,5921,5939,5941,5951,5953,5963,5969,5981,5983,6001,6011,6023,6029,6031,6037,6049,6059,6061,6067,6073,6091,6107,6109,6113,6121,6131,6133,6137,6157,6161,6163,6169,6173,6191,6193,6197,6199,6221,6227,6233,6239,6241,6253,6257,6259,6277,6281,6283,6289,6301,6313,6331,6337,6347,6353,6361,6367,6373,6379,6401,6413,6431,6443,6449,6451,6457,6463,6469,6473,6481,6491,6493,6497,6499,6509,6511,6521,6523,6529,6541,6551,6553,6571,6577,6593,6611,6613,6617,6619,6631,6637,6641,6649,6667,6673,6689,6697,6721,6731,6733,6737,6739,6749,6751,6757,6761,6763,6781,6791,6793,6817,6833,6841,6847,6859,6877,6889,6899,6901,6911,6913,6929,6931,6941,6943,6961,6971,6973,6983,6989,6991,6997,7001,7009,7019,7027,7033,7051,7057,7067,7069,7073,7081,7093,7097,7099,7117,7121,7123,7129,7141,7151,7153,7157,7159,7169,7181,7187,7193,7199,7201,7211,7213,7219,7237,7241,7243,7249,7253,7261,7267,7291,7297,7307,7309,7313,7321,7327,7333,7337,7339,7351,7361,7373,7379,7391,7393,7403,7409,7411,7417,7421,7423,7429,7433,7451,7453,7457,7459,7471,7477,7481,7489,7501,7513,7531,7537,7561,7571,7573,7577,7579,7589,7591,7597,7601,7603,7627,7633,7649,7657,7673,7681,7691,7697,7699,7709,7711,7717,7723,7729,7739,7741,7747,7753,7757,7759,7769,7771,7789,7793,7799,7801,7813,7841,7853,7859,7871,7873,7883,7891,7897,7901,7909,7913,7921,7933,7937,7943,7957,7963,7969,7981,7991,7993,7997,7999,8009,8011,8017,8021,8023,8041,8051,8053,8077,8081,8083,8089,8093,8101,8107,8129,8137,8149,8161,8177,8191,8203,8209,8219,8221,8233,8243,8257,8269,8273,8287,8299,8317,8327,8329,8333,8341,8353,8363,8369,8371,8377,8401,8411,8413,8417,8419,8437,8441,8443,8459,8461,8467,8473,8479,8497,8501,8503,8509,8513,8531,8537,8543,8557,8563,8569,8579,8581,8587,8593,8597,8599,8609,8611,8641,8651,8653,8657,8669,8671,8677,8681,8683,8689,8717,8723,8737,8747,8749,8753,8761,8767,8773,8777,8779,8797,8801,8803,8809,8821,8833,8849,8857,8881,8917,8921,8923,8929,8933,8941,8947,8971,8977,8989,8993,9001,9017,9041,9043,9049,9053,9061,9067,9073,9083,9089,9091,9097,9101,9103,9109,9113,9133,9137,9143,9157,9169,9197,9203,9209,9217,9227,9229,9241,9253,9257,9259,9277,9281,9287,9301,9307,9313,9337,9341,9343,9349,9353,9361,9367,9389,9397,9409,9419,9421,9427,9433,9437,9439,9449,9451,9469,9473,9479,9481,9493,9517,9521,9523,9529,9533,9547,9553,9577,9589,9601,9617,9631,9643,9649,9659,9661,9673,9683,9697,9707,9713,9727,9739,9757,9761,9763,9769,9773,9781,9787,9809,9817,9829,9841,9857,9871,9883,9889,9899,9901,9913,9923,9937,9949,9953,9967,9979,9997,10001,10009,10013,10021,10027,10033,10049,10057,10069,10081,10091,10093,10097,10099,10109,10111,10117,10121,10123,10141,10151,10153,10177,10193,10201,10207,10219,10237,10249,10259,10261,10271,10273,10289,10291,10301,10303,10321,10331,10333,10343,10349,10351,10357,10361,10369,10379,10387,10393,10411,10417,10427,10429,10433,10441,10453,10457,10459,10477,10481,10483,10489,10501,10511,10513,10517,10519,10529,10541,10547,10553,10559,10561,10571,10573,10579,10597,10601,10603,10609,10613,10621,10627,10651,10657,10667,10669,10673,10681,10687,10693,10697,10699,10711,10721,10733,10739,10751,10753,10763,10769,10771,10777,10781,10783,10789,10793,10811,10813,10817,10819,10831,10837,10841,10849,10861,10873,10891,10897,10921,10931,10933,10937,10939,10949,10951,10957,10961,10963,10987,10993,11009,11017,11033,11041,11051,11057,11059,11069,11071,11077,11083,11089,11099,11101,11107,11113,11117,11119,11129,11131,11149,11153,11159,11161,11173,11201,11213,11219,11231,11233,11243,11251,11257,11261,11269,11273,11281,11293,11297,11303,11317,11323,11329,11341,11351,11353,11357,11359,11369,11371,11377,11381,11383,11401,11411,11413,11437,11441,11443,11449,11453,11461,11467,11489,11497,11509,11521,11531,11533,11537,11539,11549,11551,11561,11563,11569,11581,11591,11593,11611,11617,11633,11647,11659,11677,11681,11689,11699,11701,11713,11723,11729,11731,11741,11743,11761,11771,11773,11777,11779,11789,11791,11797,11801,11803,11821,11831,11833,11857,11873,11881,11887,11899,11917,11929,11939,11941,11951,11953,11969,11971,11981,11983,12001,12011,12013,12017,12029,12031,12037,12041,12043,12049,12071,12073,12091,12097,12107,12109,12113,12121,12127,12133,12137,12139,12157,12161,12167,12169,12181,12193,12209,12217,12223,12241,12251,12253,12277,12287,12289,12301,12307,12317,12319,12331,12337,12349,12353,12361,12377,12391,12401,12433,12449,12461,12499,12511,12529,12541,12557,12571,12583,12589,12601,12611,12613,12617,12619,12629,12631,12637,12641,12643,12661,12671,12673,12697,12713,12721,12727,12739,12757,12769,12779,12781,12787,12793,12797,12799,12809,12811,12829,12833,12839,12841,12853,12881,12889,12907,12913,12923,12937,12947,12949,12959,12961,12973,12977,12979,12989,12991,12997,13001,13003,13009,13021,13031,13033,13051,13057,13073,13081,13087,13099,13117,13121,13129,13141,13151,13163,13169,13171,13183,13201,13211,13213,13229,13231,13241,13249,13259,13261,13267,13273,13291,13297,13309,13313,13331,13333,13337,13339,13357,13361,13369,13373,13381,13393,13397,13399,13409,13421,13427,13439,13441,13451,13453,13457,13459,13469,13471,13477,13481,13483,13501,13511,13513,13537,13553,13561,13567,13579,13597,13609,13619,13621,13631,13633,13649,13651,13661,13663,13681,13691,13693,13703,13709,13711,13717,13721,13729,13739,13747,13753,13771,13777,13787,13789,13793,13801,13813,13817,13819,13837,13841,13843,13849,13861,13871,13873,13877,13879,13889,13901,13907,13913,13919,13921,13931,13933,13939,13957,13961,13963,13969,13973,13981,13987,14011,14017,14027,14029,14033,14041,14047,14053,14057,14059,14071,14081,14093,14099,14111,14113,14123,14129,14131,14137,14141,14143,14149,14153,14171,14173,14177,14179,14191,14197,14201,14209,14221,14233,14251,14257,14281,14291,14293,14297,14299,14309,14311,14317,14321,14323,14347,14353,14369,14377,14393,14401,14411,14417,14419,14429,14431,14437,14443,14449,14459,14461,14467,14473,14477,14479,14489,14491,14509,14513,14519,14521,14533,14561,14573,14579,14591,14593,14603,14611,14617,14621,14629,14633,14641,14653,14657,14663,14677,14683,14689,14701,14711,14713,14717,14719,14729,14731,14737,14741,14743,14761,14771,14773,14797,14801,14803,14809,14813,14821,14827,14849,14857,14869,14881,14891,14893,14897,14899,14909,14911,14921,14923,14929,14941,14951,14953,14971,14977,14993,15007,15019,15037,15041,15049,15059,15061,15073,15083,15089,15091,15101,15103,15121,15131,15133,15137,15139,15149,15151,15157,15161,15163,15181,15191,15193,15217,15233,15241,15247,15259,15277,15289,15299,15301,15311,15313,15329,15331,15341,15343,15361,15371,15373,15377,15389,15391,15397,15401,15403,15409,15431,15433,15451,15457,15467,15469,15473,15481,15487,15493,15497,15499,15517,15521,15527,15529,15541,15553,15569,15577,15583,15601,15611,15613,15637,15647,15649,15661,15667,15677,15679,15691,15697,15709,15713,15721,15737,15751,15761,15793,15809,15821,15859,15871,15889,15901,15917,15931,15943,15949,15961,15971,15973,15977,15979,15989,15991,15997,16001,16003,16021,16031,16033,16057,16073,16081,16087,16099,16117,16129,16139,16141,16147,16153,16157,16159,16169,16171,16189,16193,16199,16201,16213,16241,16249,16267,16273,16283,16297,16307,16309,16319,16321,16333,16337,16339,16349,16351,16357,16361,16363,16369,16381,16391,16393,16411,16417,16433,16441,16447,16459,16477,16481,16489,16501,16511,16523,16529,16531,16543,16561,16571,16573,16589,16591,16601,16609,16619,16621,16627,16633,16651,16657,16669,16673,16691,16693,16697,16699,16717,16721,16729,16733,16741,16753,16757,16759,16769,16781,16787,16799,16801,16811,16813,16817,16819,16829,16831,16837,16841,16843,16861,16871,16873,16897,16913,16921,16927,16939,16957,16969,16979,16981,16991,16993,17009,17011,17021,17023,17041,17051,17053,17063,17069,17071,17077,17081,17089,17099,17107,17113,17131,17137,17147,17149,17153,17161,17173,17177,17179,17197,17201,17203,17209,17221,17231,17233,17237,17239,17249,17261,17267,17273,17279,17281,17291,17293,17299,17317,17321,17323,17329,17333,17341,17347,17371,17377,17387,17389,17393,17401,17407,17413,17417,17419,17431,17441,17453,17459,17471,17473,17483,17489,17491,17497,17501,17503,17509,17513,17533,17537,17543,17557,17569,17593,17599,17611,17617,17627,17629,17641,17651,17653,17663,17677,17681,17683,17693,17707,17713,17723,17737,17741,17743,17749,17753,17761,17771,17777,17779,17803,17809,17819,17821,17827,17833,17849,17851,17867,17869,17873,17881,17887,17893,17903,17909,17911,17917,17921,17933,17939,17951,17953,17957,17963,17977,17981,17993,18001,18017,18041,18047,18049,18059,18061,18077,18089,18101,18113,18131,18143,18157,18161,18173,18191,18197,18209,18227,18233,18241,18251,18253,18257,18269,18281,18293,18299,18317,18323,18329,18337,18341,18353,18359,18379,18397,18401,18413,18419,18437,18443,18449,18457,18461,18467,18481,18491,18493,18497,18499,18509,18511,18517,18521,18523,18541,18551,18553,18577,18593,18601,18607,18619,18637,18649,18659,18661,18671,18673,18689,18691,18701,18703,18721,18731,18733,18743,18749,18751,18757,18761,18769,18779,18787,18793,18811,18817,18827,18829,18833,18841,18853,18857,18859,18877,18881,18883,18889,18901,18911,18913,18917,18919,18929,18941,18947,18953,18959,18961,18971,18973,18979,18997,19001,19003,19009,19013,19021,19027,19051,19057,19067,19069,19073,19081,19087,19093,19097,19099,19111,19121,19133,19139,19151,19153,19163,19169,19171,19177,19181,19183,19189,19193,19211,19213,19217,19219,19231,19237,19241,19249,19261,19273,19291,19297,19321,19339,19357,19361,19379,19381,19391,19393,19403,19409,19421,19423,19441,19451,19463,19469,19471,19477,19489,19499,19501,19507,19513,19531,19547,19549,19553,19561,19571,19573,19577,19597,19601,19603,19609,19613,19631,19633,19637,19639,19661,19667,19673,19679,19681,19693,19697,19699,19717,19721,19723,19729,19741,19753,19771,19777,19787,19793,19801,19807,19813,19819,19841,19853,19871,19883,19889,19891,19897,19903,19909,19913,19921,19931,19933,19937,19939,19949,19951,19961,19963,19969,19981,19991,19993,20011,20017,20033,20051,20053,20057,20059,20071,20077,20081,20089,20107,20113,20129,20137,20161,20171,20173,20177,20179,20189,20191,20197,20201,20203,20221,20231,20233,20257,20273,20281,20287,20299,20317,20329,20339,20341,20351,20353,20369,20371,20381,20383,20401,20411,20413,20423,20429,20431,20437,20441,20449,20459,20467,20473,20491,20497,20507,20509,20513,20521,20533,20537,20539,20557,20561,20563,20569,20581,20591,20593,20597,20599,20609,20621,20627,20633,20639,20641,20651,20653,20659,20677,20681,20683,20689,20693,20701,20707,20731,20737,20747,20749,20753,20761,20767,20773,20777,20779,20791,20801,20813,20819,20831,20833,20843,20849,20851,20857,20861,20863,20869,20873,20891,20893,20897,20899,20911,20917,20921,20929,20941,20953,20971,20977,21001,21011,21013,21017,21019,21029,21031,21037,21041,21043,21067,21073,21089,21097,21113,21121,21131,21137,21139,21149,21151,21157,21163,21169,21179,21181,21187,21193,21197,21199,21209,21211,21229,21233,21239,21241,21253,21281,21293,21299,21311,21313,21323,21331,21337,21341,21349,21353,21361,21373,21377,21383,21397,21403,21409,21421,21431,21433,21437,21439,21449,21451,21457,21461,21463,21481,21491,21493,21517,21521,21523,21529,21533,21541,21547,21569,21577,21589,21601,21617,21631,21643,21649,21659,21661,21673,21683,21697,21709,21713,21727,21739,21757,21767,21769,21773,21781,21793,21803,21809,21811,21817,21841,21851,21853,21857,21859,21877,21881,21883,21899,21901,21907,21913,21919,21937,21941,21943,21949,21953,21971,21977,21983,21997,22003,22009,22019,22021,22027,22033,22037,22039,22049,22051,22081,22091,22093,22097,22109,22111,22117,22121,22123,22129,22157,22163,22177,22187,22189,22193,22201,22207,22213,22217,22219,22237,22241,22243,22249,22261,22273,22289,22297,22321,22357,22361,22363,22369,22373,22381,22387,22411,22417,22429,22433,22441,22457,22481,22483,22489,22493,22501,22507,22513,22523,22529,22531,22537,22541,22543,22549,22553,22573,22577,22583,22597,22609,22637,22643,22649,22657,22667,22669,22681,22693,22697,22699,22717,22721,22727,22741,22747,22753,22777,22781,22783,22789,22793,22801,22807,22829,22837,22849,22859,22861,22867,22873,22877,22879,22889,22891,22909,22913,22919,22921,22933,22957,22961,22963,22969,22973,22987,22993,23017,23029,23041,23057,23071,23083,23089,23099,23101,23113,23123,23137,23147,23153,23167,23179,23197,23201,23203,23209,23213,23221,23227,23249,23257,23269,23281,23297,23311,23323,23329,23339,23341,23353,23363,23377,23389,23393,23407,23419,23437,23441,23449,23453,23461,23467,23473,23489,23497,23509,23521,23531,23533,23537,23539,23549,23551,23557,23561,23563,23581,23591,23593,23617,23633,23641,23647,23659,23677,23689,23699,23701,23711,23713,23729,23731,23741,23743,23761,23771,23773,23783,23789,23791,23797,23801,23809,23819,23827,23833,23851,23857,23867,23869,23873,23881,23893,23897,23899,23917,23921,23923,23929,23941,23951,23953,23957,23959,23969,23981,23987,23993,23999,24001,24011,24013,24019,24037,24041,24043,24049,24053,24061,24067,24091,24097,24107,24109,24113,24121,24127,24133,24137,24139,24151,24161,24173,24179,24191,24193,24203,24209,24211,24217,24221,24223,24229,24233,24251,24253,24257,24259,24271,24277,24281,24289,24301,24313,24331,24337,24361,24371,24373,24377,24379,24389,24391,24397,24401,24403,24427,24433,24449,24457,24473,24481,24491,24497,24499,24509,24511,24517,24523,24529,24539,24541,24547,24553,24557,24559,24569,24571,24589,24593,24599,24601,24613,24641,24653,24659,24671,24673,24683,24691,24697,24701,24709,24713,24721,24733,24737,24743,24757,24763,24769,24781,24791,24793,24797,24799,24809,24811,24817,24821,24823,24841,24851,24853,24877,24881,24883,24889,24893,24901,24907,24929,24937,24949,24961,24971,24973,24977,24979,24989,24991,25001,25003,25009,25021,25031,25033,25051,25057,25073,25087,25099,25117,25121,25129,25139,25141,25153,25163,25169,25171,25181,25183,25201,25211,25213,25217,25219,25229,25231,25237,25241,25243,25261,25271,25273,25297,25313,25321,25327,25339,25357,25369,25379,25381,25391,25393,25409,25411,25421,25423,25441,25451,25453,25457,25469,25471,25477,25481,25483,25489,25511,25513,25531,25537,25547,25549,25553,25561,25567,25573,25577,25579,25597,25601,25607,25609,25621,25633,25649,25657,25663,25681,25691,25693,25717,25727,25729,25741,25747,25757,25759,25771,25777,25789,25793,25801,25817,25831,25841,25873,25889,25901,25939,25951,25969,25981,25997,26011,26023,26029,26041,26051,26053,26057,26059,26069,26071,26077,26081,26083,26101,26111,26113,26137,26153,26161,26167,26179,26197,26209,26219,26221,26227,26233,26237,26239,26249,26251,26269,26273,26279,26281,26293,26321,26329,26347,26353,26363,26377,26387,26389,26399,26401,26413,26417,26419,26429,26431,26437,26441,26443,26449,26461,26471,26473,26491,26497,26513,26521,26527,26539,26557,26561,26569,26581,26591,26603,26609,26611,26623,26641,26651,26653,26669,26671,26681,26689,26699,26701,26707,26713,26731,26737,26749,26753,26771,26773,26777,26779,26797,26801,26809,26813,26821,26833,26837,26839,26849,26861,26867,26879,26881,26891,26893,26897,26899,26909,26911,26917,26921,26923,26941,26951,26953,26977,26993,27001,27007,27019,27037,27049,27059,27061,27071,27073,27089,27091,27101,27103,27121,27131,27133,27143,27149,27151,27157,27161,27169,27179,27187,27193,27211,27217,27227,27229,27233,27241,27253,27257,27259,27277,27281,27283,27289,27301,27311,27313,27317,27319,27329,27341,27347,27353,27359,27361,27371,27373,27379,27397,27401,27403,27409,27413,27421,27427,27451,27457,27467,27469,27473,27481,27487,27493,27497,27499,27511,27521,27533,27539,27551,27553,27563,27569,27571,27577,27581,27583,27589,27593,27611,27613,27617,27619,27631,27637,27641,27649,27661,27673,27691,27697,27721,27731,27733,27737,27739,27749,27751,27757,27761,27763,27787,27793,27809,27817,27833,27841,27851,27857,27859,27869,27871,27877,27883,27889,27899,27901,27907,27913,27917,27919,27929,27931,27949,27953,27959,27961,27973,28001,28013,28019,28031,28033,28043,28051,28057,28061,28069,28073,28081,28093,28097,28103,28117,28123,28129,28141,28151,28153,28157,28159,28169,28171,28177,28181,28183,28201,28211,28213,28237,28241,28243,28249,28253,28261,28267,28289,28297,28309,28321,28337,28351,28363,28369,28379,28381,28393,28403,28417,28429,28433,28447,28459,28477,28487,28489,28493,28501,28513,28523,28529,28531,28537,28561,28571,28573,28577,28579,28597,28601,28603,28619,28621,28627,28633,28639,28657,28661,28663,28669,28673,28691,28697,28703,28717,28723,28729,28739,28741,28747,28753,28757,28759,28769,28771,28801,28811,28813,28817,28829,28831,28837,28841,28843,28849,28877,28883,28897,28907,28909,28913,28921,28927,28933,28937,28939,28957,28961,28963,28969,28981,28993,29009,29017,29041,29077,29081,29083,29089,29093,29101,29107,29131,29137,29149,29153,29161,29177,29201,29203,29209,29213,29221,29227,29233,29243,29249,29251,29257,29261,29263,29269,29273,29293,29297,29303,29317,29329,29357,29363,29369,29377,29387,29389,29401,29413,29417,29419,29437,29441,29447,29461,29467,29473,29497,29501,29503,29509,29513,29521,29527,29549,29557,29569,29579,29581,29587,29593,29597,29599,29609,29611,29629,29633,29639,29641,29653,29677,29681,29683,29689,29693,29707,29713,29737,29749,29761,29777,29791,29803,29809,29819,29821,29833,29843,29857,29867,29873,29887,29899,29917,29921,29923,29929,29933,29941,29947,29969,29977,29989,30001,30017,30031,30043,30049,30059,30061,30073,30083,30097,30109,30113,30127,30139,30157,30161,30169,30173,30181,30187,30193,30209,30217,30229,30241,30251,30253,30257,30259,30283,30299,30301,30307,30313,30323,30329,30337,30347,30349,30353,30361,30367,30383,30389,30391,30397,30413,30419,30431,30433,30449,30451,30467,30469,30473,30481,30487,30493,30497,30523,30529,30539,30547,30553,30557,30559,30571,30577,30593,30617,30623,30637,30641,30643,30649,30661,30673,30683,30689,30691,30697,30701,30703,30713,30721,30733,30743,30757,30763,30769,30803,30809,30811,30817,30823,30829,30833,30841,30859,30881,30889,30913,30923,30929,30931,30937,30941,30943,30949,30953,30973,30977,30983,30997,31009,31033,31039,31051,31057,31067,31069,31081,31091,31093,31103,31117,31121,31123,31133,31147,31153,31163,31177,31181,31183,31189,31193,31201,31211,31217,31219,31243,31249,31259,31261,31267,31273,31289,31291,31307,31309,31313,31321,31327,31333,31343,31349,31351,31357,31361,31373,31379,31391,31393,31403,31411,31417,31427,31429,31433,31441,31447,31453,31457,31459,31483,31489,31499,31501,31513,31517,31519,31529,31531,31537,31543,31553,31571,31583,31597,31601,31603,31609,31613,31621,31627,31643,31649,31651,31657,31663,31669,31673,31681,31693,31697,31723,31729,31753,31763,31769,31771,31777,31781,31783,31789,31793,31819,31837,31841,31849,31873,31883,31889,31891,31897,31901,31903,31909,31921,31931,31933,31937,31939,31949,31951,31957,31961,31963,31981,31991,31993,32017,32033,32051,32057,32063,32077,32083,32089,32093,32101,32107,32113,32129,32149,32161,32173,32183,32189,32191,32197,32201,32203,32209,32213,32233,32237,32243,32257,32267,32269,32273,32281,32293,32297,32299,32317,32321,32323,32329,32341,32351,32353,32357,32359,32369,32381,32387,32393,32399,32401,32411,32413,32419,32437,32441,32443,32449,32453,32461,32467,32491,32497,32507,32509,32513,32521,32527,32533,32537,32539,32551,32561,32573,32579,32591,32593,32603,32609,32611,32617,32621,32623,32629,32633,32651,32653,32657,32659,32671,32677,32681,32689,32701,32713,32731,32737,32761,32779,32797,32801,32819,32821,32831,32833,32843,32849,32861,32863,32881,32891,32903,32909,32911,32917,32929,32939,32941,32947,32953,32971,32987,32989,32993,33001,33011,33013,33017,33037,33041,33043,33049,33053,33071,33073,33077,33079,33101,33107,33113,33119,33121,33133,33137,33139,33157,33161,33163,33169,33181,33193,33211,33217,33227,33233,33241,33247,33253,33259,33281,33293,33311,33323,33329,33331,33337,33343,33349,33353,33361,33371,33373,33377,33379,33389,33391,33401,33403,33409,33421,33431,33433,33451,33457,33473,33491,33493,33497,33499,33511,33517,33521,33529,33547,33553,33569,33577,33601,33611,33613,33617,33629,33641,33653,33659,33683,33689,33697,33701,33713,33739,33757,33773,33779,33797,33809,33821,33827,33833,33841,33851,33853,33857,33869,33871,33877,33881,33883,33889,33911,33913,33931,33937,33953,33961,33967,33979,33997,34001,34009,34019,34021,34031,34033,34043,34049,34051,34061,34063,34081,34091,34093,34103,34109,34117,34121,34129,34141,34147,34171,34177,34187,34189,34193,34201,34211,34213,34217,34219,34241,34243,34249,34253,34261,34271,34273,34277,34289,34301,34313,34319,34331,34333,34337,34339,34357,34361,34369,34373,34381,34387,34393,34411,34417,34427,34429,34441,34453,34457,34459,34471,34481,34493,34499,34511,34513,34523,34529,34537,34541,34543,34549,34553,34561,34571,34577,34579,34603,34609,34619,34621,34627,34633,34649,34651,34667,34669,34673,34681,34687,34693,34703,34709,34711,34717,34721,34733,34739,34751,34753,34757,34763,34777,34781,34793,34801,34817,34841,34847,34849,34859,34861,34877,34889,34901,34913,34931,34943,34957,34961,34973,34991,34997,35009,35027,35033,35041,35051,35053,35057,35069,35081,35093,35099,35117,35123,35129,35137,35141,35153,35159,35179,35197,35201,35213,35219,35237,35243,35249,35257,35261,35267,35281,35291,35293,35297,35309,35321,35327,35333,35339,35351,35377,35389,35393,35411,35417,35423,35429,35449,35453,35473,35477,35489,35513,35519,35521,35531,35533,35537,35549,35561,35573,35597,35603,35617,35627,35629,35633,35657,35663,35669,35681,35699,35713,35723,35729,35741,35747,35753,35771,35789,35801,35807,35809,35813,35831,35837,35851,35857,35867,35869,35879,35881,35887,35893,35897,35921,35923,35929,35947,35953,35963,35969,35971,35977,35989,35993,36011,36013,36017,36019,36031,36037,36047,36049,36053,36061,36077,36083,36089,36097,36107,36109,36121,36131,36133,36137,36139,36149,36151,36157,36161,36163,36187,36193,36203,36209,36217,36221,36223,36229,36233,36241,36247,36257,36269,36287,36289,36299,36301,36307,36313,36317,36319,36329,36331,36349,36353,36359,36361,36373,36401,36409,36427,36433,36443,36457,36467,36469,36479,36481,36493,36497,36499,36509,36511,36517,36521,36523,36529,36541,36551,36553,36571,36577,36593,36601,36607,36619,36637,36641,36649,36661,36671,36683,36689,36691,36703,36721,36731,36733,36749,36751,36761,36769,36779,36781,36787,36793,36811,36817,36829,36833,36851,36853,36857,36859,36877,36881,36889,36893,36901,36913,36917,36919,36929,36941,36947,36959,36961,36979,36991,37003,37021,37063,37069,37081,37091,37097,37099,37109,37111,37117,37123,37129,37141,37151,37153,37171,37193,37201,37207,37237,37241,37249,37259,37267,37273,37277,37279,37291,37297,37309,37313,37319,37321,37333,37339,37361,37369,37393,37403,37409,37417,37427,37439,37447,37453,37477,37481,37483,37489,37493,37501,37507,37529,37537,37549,37561,37577,37591,37603,37609,37619,37621,37633,37649,37661,37699,37711,37729,37741,37757,37771,37783,37789,37801,37817,37831,37841,37867,37873,37889,37897,37913,37921,37927,37937,37969,37997,38011,38047,38077,38081,38089,38107,38113,38123,38137,38147,38149,38159,38161,38173,38177,38179,38189,38191,38203,38209,38219,38221,38233,38237,38239,38249,38251,38257,38273,38279,38281,38293,38299,38317,38321,38329,38341,38351,38363,38369,38371,38383,38401,38411,38413,38417,38419,38429,38431,38441,38443,38449,38461,38471,38473,38491,38497,38513,38527,38539,38557,38561,38569,38579,38581,38593,38603,38609,38611,38621,38623,38641,38653,38657,38663,38677,38683,38701,38711,38713,38719,38729,38737,38741,38743,38749,38761,38771,38797,38803,38809,38813,38821,38827,38833,38849,38869,38881,38893,38903,38909,38911,38917,38921,38923,38929,38933,38953,38957,38963,38977,38981,38989,38993,39001,39013,39017,39023,39037,39043,39049,39061,39073,39089,39097,39121,39149,39161,39167,39169,39173,39211,39217,39229,39233,39241,39257,39281,39283,39289,39293,39301,39307,39313,39329,39337,39353,39379,39397,39401,39409,39433,39451,39457,39481,39493,39497,39499,39511,39521,39533,39539,39551,39553,39563,39569,39577,39581,39583,39589,39593,39601,39607,39617,39629,39647,39649,39653,39659,39671,39691,39701,39703,39709,39713,39721,39761,39773,39779,39791,39793,39803,39811,39821,39827,39833,39839,39841,39857,39863,39869,39877,39881,39883,39889,39901,39913,39923,39929,39931,39937,39947,39953,39961,39979,40003,40007,40009,40013,40021,40037,40051,40057,40067,40081,40093,40109,40127,40129,40139,40141,40157,40171,40219,40241,40247,40253,40267,40273,40277,40289,40297,40301,40307,40319

65536: This makes my answer go over the character limit (32768 numbers)

105953: 1-105952
```

Comment: I think something is wrong here, you cannot balance one on a 100 hole centrifuge but you can balance 8,18,28,48,58,68,78,88 (this list is perhaps not complete).

Comment: I must've accidentally cut the one out, as for the other numbers,  have to look into that

Comment: Thank you very much for updating your list! If possible, you could just count the number of outputs for the cases where you get such huge lists - I did not think that throu really=)

Comment: @flawr I updated the list

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - <strike>39</strike> 37 bytes

A direct translation of @Wrzlprmft's python answer.

```
f.Am>.asm^.n1c*.jZyk.nZQd^10_9.cUQTSQ
```

Explanation and probably further golfing coming soon.

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f.Am%3E.asm%5E.n1c*.jZyk.nZQd%5E10_9.cUQTSQ&input=9&debug=1).